# Place a link in the watch companion editor app

Tags: kotlin, wear-os, watchface

I develop watchfaces and the default configurator is quite limited.
I want to show a choice of 50 backgrounds to the user and right now I can't because of this error :

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The estimated wire size of the supplied UserStyleSchemas for watch face com.xxxxx is too big at 326242 bytes. UserStyleSchemas get sent to the companion over bluetooth and should be as small as possible for this to be performant.
    at androidx.wear.watchface.WatchFaceService$EngineWrapper.validateSchemaWireSize$watchface_release(WatchFaceService.kt:2250)
    at androidx.wear.watchface.WatchFaceService$EngineWrapper$createWatchFaceInternal$1.invokeSuspend(WatchFaceService.kt:1964)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@722ab7c, Handler (android.os.Handler) {7eafc05}.immediate]
```

I see some other apps having dedicated companion app on phone.
But because the user might not install it, they also have a link in the "watch companion" app :

[image]

If you click it : if the app is installed, it opens, otherwise it brings you to the play store.

I would like to have a link like this for my apps.

Do you know how I can do it ?
(I work in kotlin)

I created a shema and tried the options :
    `UserStyleSetting.ListUserStyleSetting UserStyleSetting.CustomValueUserStyleSetting UserStyleSetting.BooleanUserStyleSetting UserStyleSetting.DoubleRangeUserStyleSetting`

In the manifest there is a boolean to activate or not the configuration :
    `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.companionBuiltinConfigurationEnabled" android:value="true" />`

I want to disable it and replace it by a link to the play store

Thanks !!